# How do I parse/skip specific characters in attrparsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm trying to learn how to use the attrparsec module and so am practicing by parsing one of my log files.

I have the following code for the beginning of a line parser:

```
 lineParser :: Parser LogEntry
 lineParser = do
    theMonth <- monthParser
    skipSpace
    theDate <- decimal
    skipSpace
    theHour <- decimal
    skipColon
    theMinute <- decimal
    skipColon
    theSecond <- decimal
    return  LogEntry { monthOfYear = theMonth,  dayOfMonth = theDate,
    hourOfDay = theHour, minuteOfHour = theMinute, secondOfMinute = theSecond}
```

but I'm having trouble with the skipColon function. I've tried various versions such as

```
skipColon = isColon 
   where isColon c = c == ':'
```

but I just get type errors

I would have liked to have simply written something like

```
skipChar ':'
```

but haven't been able to figure that out either.

Ran into all sorts of type errors around Char vs Word8 but most search results where about converting Word8 to Char, not the other way round.

Would appreciate some guidance. Many thanks.

Comment: "but I just get type errors" - What type errors?  Can you include those with your question?

Comment: Do you mean `attoparsec`?

Comment: There should be something along the lines of `char ':'`. To skip it, just write it there without a `<-`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean attoparsec. Just so used to typing 'attr' in other contexts.

Comment: Yes, char ':' did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: The type errors were around Word8 expected but Char was seen.

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered?

Comment: @David Write an answer using the big text box below (or convince AJFarmar to). Then click the green check mark next to that answer. It is considered fine etiquette to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJFarmer posted the best answer.
Simply use

```
char ':'
```

However, you'll get a warning about a discarded value so to avoid that warning write

```
_ <- char ':'
```

Thanks for answering.